# How to modify or add a json field from logstash to work with geo_point in ElasticSearch and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a json file with this structure:

```
{"vhost": "8.8.8.8", "host": "8.8.8.8", "port": 80, "ip": "189.191.116.19", "host.latitude":"40.408599853515625","host.longitude":"-3.692199945449829"}
```

And I have a logstash config file like this:

```
input {
  stdin {
    type => "json"
  }
}
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
        stdout{}
}
```

I want to transform the json records so that I can use the geo_point type in ES and Kibana. According to the official documentation in 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html the latitude and longitude fields have to be in a format like this:

```
"pin" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 41.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
        }
    }
```

My question is, how can I transform from logstash the json input so that I can use the geo_point?. I guess that I can not modify the json structure itself but maybe I can add a new field with the location estructure required by the geo_point type.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to concatenate the two field `host.latitude` and `host.longitude` into another field that can be mapped as [geopoint as string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html).

You just need to add one more `mutate` filter after your `json` filter like this:

```
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
       add_field => { "location" => "%{host.latitude},%{host.longitude}" }
    }
}
```

As a result, the `location` field will be created which you can map as a `geo_point` type in your mapping.

Comment: Your link is 404ing, rather add the main content from the linked page

Comment: The link is fixed